# Android Studio - Google code scanner: Error in starting scanner

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, qr-code

I'm having some trouble getting **Google code scanner** (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner) to work on the phone emulator in my IDE. Whenever I try to start the scanner using my button, the scanner doesn't come out and then I keep seeing this error message in my Logcat: `com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Waiting for the Barcode UI module to be downloaded.`

I thought it might have something to do with Google Play services, so I tried adding/installing it on my emulator through `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Google Play services.` I also added INTERNET permissions to my manifest, but it still isn't working.

Oddly enough, when I tried running it on my own mobile phone through USB, the scanner worked without any issues. Do you have any suggestions on what I can do to get it working on the emulator? Thank you so much for taking the time to read my problem! I appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks in advance!

This is my code for reference:

```
// Imports that I've used
import com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.GmsBarcodeScannerOptions
import com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.GmsBarcodeScanning

// Configurations added on my AndroidManifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode_ui"/>

// Dependency used (build.gradle)
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-code-scanner:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0'

// Configurations added on settings.graddle
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


// Code
private fun qrScanner() {
        val options: GmsBarcodeScannerOptions = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE
            )
            .build()
        val scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this, options)
        scanner.startScan()
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcode ->
                // Task completed successfully
                val rawValue: String? = barcode.rawValue
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener {
                // Task canceled
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Scanning cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.i("MyTag", e.toString())
            }
        binding.btnScan.setOnClickListener {
            // Start scanning
            scanner.startScan()
        }
    }
```